# Taizé prayer in Vienna: where?

Tags: austria, religion, vienna

I'm going to Vienna for 5 days. Where I live use to go to the [Taize](http://www.taize.fr)' prayer in some Parrish. 
I know this is international and that many people, after coming back to Taizé, start to pray the same way in small group within the local church.

Does any of you know if there are any regular Taizé prayers in Vienna and if it would be possible to get in contact with them and to join the prayer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is/was a community around Taize activities in Vienna, but they don´t seem to be very active anymore. Many informations and activitiy dates in the net are very outdated
(eg. nothing new since 2013).

The only thing which could be active to this day (*could*) is
A weekly Taize prayer,
each Wednesday 19:00 (except Christmas week)
in the St.Ruprechts church 1010 Wien. ([GoogleMaps](https://www.google.at/maps/place/Ruprechtskirche/@48.212016,16.374395,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x476d07a19768284b:0xfbb78be267e68f32))
A contact mail address is given, if you want to ask if this is still valid: *taize.wien@gmail.at*

Nearest stations of public transport is *Schwedenplatz*
of subway lines U1 and U4 (or station Morzinplatz by Bus).

Source (in german) eg. [Jugendtreffen.info](http://www.jugendtreffen.info/gebete/at/wien/) (and more sites saying the same thing).

Comment: Thanks, I just wrote them, I'm not sure anybody is answering... BTW the correct address is taize.wien@gmx.at

Comment: It worked! With the correct address they answered! Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Having been to Taizé in the past, they might have information in Taizé itself. 
They ask the guests whether they do have regular activities and many people who go to Taizé will inform them on regular meetings and maybe also special events.

I would send an e-mail to the meetings@taize.fr as indicated on this website: http://www.taize.fr/en_article332.html And ask them to hand on the mail to a better person if they know one.
The page is a bit older but Taizé does not repair what is not broken, so I would not worry about that.